# PhantomJS injectJS path

Tags: phantomjs

Let a script run by PhantomJS be located at:

```
http://www.fooaddr.com/folder1/scriptToRun.js
```

*meaning that the path on my host is `(root)/folder1/scriptToRun.js`*

I'm opening a page and injecting external .js in it like this:

```
var page = webPage.create();
page.open("http://www.fooaddr.com/folder2/foopage.html",function(status){
    page.injectJs('myscript.js');
});
```

And so I want to know if the path for the injected file is relative to the script running with PhantomJS, or relative to the opened page.

Comment: What is `scriptToRun.js`? If it is a phantomjs script or a part of it, you can't use `injectJs` or `includeJs`. Those make only sense for page scripts like jQuery, d3.js or your custom page helpers.

Comment: `scriptToRun.js` is the script run by phantomJS

Comment: @zbMax Have you found an answer? Doing some tests seems to me that the `injectJs` path is relative to the path where PhantomJS is launched.

Comment: @sgargal Yes, currently, my js script launched by PhantomJS injects other scripts with path relative to the current script location. According to my question context, `scriptToRun.js` and `myscript.js` are located in the same folder.